# Is this painting by a famous artist?

Tags: art

Is the painting below by a significant artist? This painting has a fascinating history that I will share if it turns out that it is by an interesting artist.

I have done the inverse image search on Google and that did not reveal anything. I have also asked all of my artist friends that they indicated that this was painted by at least a very well-trained artist.

[image]

Comment: How is this a question about history?

Comment: It's a question about art history. Is this painting by a historically significant artist?

Comment: There might be a signature in the lower left, can you provide more detail there?

Comment: `This painting has a fascinating history that I will share if it turns out that it is by an interesting artist.` Why are you withholding this information? Knowing where an image came from is often very helpful for identification.

Answer (score 2):

Its very hard to write something about the painting as you didnt get us more details. This is the reason why my answer will be based only on my opinion.

First of all, because of the background of this painting, I probably guess that this has to have been painted aproximately at the and of 19th century or the a beginning of 20th. Anyway, the style of this image is old school/a bit exotic. Because of this, I guess that could be modernism/postmodernism/Art Nouveau painting.

So with this conviction, I tried to search for a similar painting style by some artist on auction sites, sites like [wikiart](https://www.wikiart.org/en/paintings-by-genre/nude-painting-nu?select=featured) at so on.

In my opinion, this is not a painting done by a world famous artist, but I have to admit the style of this paiting is really good.

In the end when you want to know artist by this painting, you should give us more details as size, weight and picture of whole painting even with picture frame. If you really want to know that artist you should propably consider an auction valuation.

P.S. This is just my opinion about this painting, if somebody hae more details about this, I would be really glad to know them. Last but not least this is just my opinion as you know with this information I can't do more. So please dont blame me for that.

Comment: The lady's hairdo is rather 1950ish.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not an answer, but too long for a comment.

As mentioned in another answer, there is not enough information to reliably attribute the painting. The image seems trimmed; I don't see the artist's signature to begin with.

JPEG serves not so well to the palette, but from what I see it doesn't look very balanced. The composition is way off (check the left shoulder and the left arm).

The model's hairdo hints at the fifties (likely US, but possibly Italian).